# Requires a generic approach to validate control of ASP.Net form

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a B2B we app having lots of forms taking input from registered users. So validation is mandatory there. I am using 3 tier architecture for my app. I am just ignoring server validation controls and client side validations. Instead i am thinking of Code Behind based validation, which i know will increase hit to my server, but too is most secure, if I am not wrong.

So what i am thinking is,

1. to enumerate all the controls of the page and check their validity. But this wayI can check only whether it is empty or not. Also I have to write it on each and every page.

   1. Another approach, if i can set the maxlength , mandatory etc somewhere in my Model Layer where I have skeleton classes,and compare it while save button hit and tell what is missing and where.
2. Some common method that will take entire page controls as array of controls and check for validity...

Please guide me which one is possible or any other good solution.So that i can avoid code repetitions.

```
Model Layer means

public class Employee
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: thanks , i have updated. I think its clear now.. i need some generic approach for form validation.

Comment: Can you explain why you have ruled out the server-side validation controls, such as <asp:RequiredFieldValidator>? These do both client- and server-side validation and do pretty much exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a set of controls that inherit from ASP.NET controls, only with (a)additional type classification. For example: TextBox that accepts an attribute of DataType (enum) and values like: int, double, email etc. Another idea is for int type add a min/max values (i.e 15-32). And (b) a Validate function that returns true/false if the value matches the datatype.
Then, create a page base that inherits from Page and exposes a function called ValidateAllMyControls that iterates through all those special controls that are in use in the current form and calls the Validate function for each one. If one of them returns false - the form is not valid. :)